# How to do different javascript actions with two buttons in one form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I'm trying to do two different javascript actions with jquery for my php form which has two submit buttons: 'save' and 'next'. The idea is that both button submits form that saves data into db, but while 'next' goes through client-side validation and progress further, the 'save' just skips validation, returns true and the user stays on the form.

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="?action=my_php_form">
    <input type="submit" name="save" class="save" id="save" value="save"/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" id="next" class="next" value="next"/>
</form>
```

I already managed to succeed when user clicks either 'save' or 'next' after reload, but if user clicks 'next', launches validation and submit returns false, he cant click 'save' and ignore validation anymore. What might be the cause of this?

```
$(function() {
    //Lets skip the whole thing if save is clicked
    $('#save').click(function() {
        $('#form').submit(function() {  
            return true;
        });
    });
    $('#next').click(function() {
        $('#form').submit(function() {
            var invalid = 0;
            //A lot of crazy validation, if some invalid stuff then increment increment invalid
            if(invalid > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would do something like this :

```
$(function() {
    //Lets skip the whole thing if save is clicked
    //Actually, no binding is needed as the button is already a submit button
    //Thx to Ocanal

    $('#next').click(function() {
        var invalid = 0;
        //Validation process
        if(invalid) {
            $('#form').submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No need to have a handler for #save button, It's already a submit button.

Comment: Ah I see, should have figured out this myself 'doh', but many thanks you did it for me!

Comment: @ocanal you're right, I was blinded by the OP example ^^. I edited my answer according to your remark. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you skip validation, especially if it so crazy ? Anyway the problem is here

```
$('#form').submit(function() { ... }
```

this doesn't overwrite the submit event handler, this ADDS a function to it. Therefore if you first click `next` then `save` , the function you defined for next will still be triggered when clicking on save.

While it's not clear with the notation, it's quite logic : that's what allows you to "add" action to your documentReady event from wherever you wish, not only from a central place.

Comment: I see your point here. I also was wondering if this was somehow my problem, but couldnt figure out how to tackle it. Thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different type for your non-submit button.

You'll want something like this:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="?action=my_php_form">
    <input type="submit" name="save" class="save" id="save" value="save"/>
    <input type="button" name="next" id="next" class="next" value="next"/>
</form>
```

I think what's happening to you now is that both buttons are acting as your "submit" button, so the form is trying to submit, regardless of which button you're clicking, or what functions you've added to the EventListener.

Comment: Having both button as submitting the same form will help me when pre-processing the form on server-side and handling different actions, as I still want to perform the form submit with both buttons. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Java Script is created every time when refreshing the page. It's important to understand that.

Now, if you click on the button `'Save'` of type submit, your information will pack up in the form packet and sent to the server. The submit action requires reloading of the page(!).
Therefore, if you want to keep values ​​in fields (if that's what you want) you may use PHP.

Using PHP is not complicated. I combine the code inside the `<body>` tag and before the `<form>` tag.
The code checks whether there is a value in the `'Save'` field of `$_POST` variable, if true, we will save the received values.

And then, I present the values ​​using variable access `<? = $name ?>`. That's it.

```
<?php
    $name = "";
    $credit = "";
    if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $credit = $_POST['creditCard'];
    }
?>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="good.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$name ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="creditCard" value="<?=$credit ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="save" class="save" id="save" value="save"/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" id="next" class="next" value="next"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is irrelevant to my question. I wasn't asking how to return post values back into the input fields.